# How to mantain Javascript functionality when adding CollectionType forms in symfony

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony

I have made a **form** with **symfony** with a **CollectionType** field, to add embedded forms for two related entities.

Everything works fine but some of the fields in the embedded form, are **dateType** fields, and I would like to use the **datepicker** javascript call when I select them.

After doing all the work I find the **datepicker popups** do not work which make sense since the form has been loaded via javascript. *But then, how can I do to get them working?*

> NOTE: I do not write any code, since I have followed the standard
> procedure proposed by symfony.com documentation. But will be happy to
> post it here on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the new date input fields inside the javascript code (where you add a new row to the collection). Here is an example as you didn't post any code.

```
function addFormToCollection($collectionHolderClass) {
    var $collectionHolder = $('.' + $collectionHolderClass);

    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    var newForm = prototype;
    
    newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    $collectionHolder.append($newFormLi);

    // initialize new DateTime fields
    var $newRow = $collectionHolder..children().last();
    $newRow.children('.dateTime').each(function(){
        initializeDatePicker($(this));
    });
}
```